# Basic Request: How to Get Text Input in Cocos2d Application

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, user-input

I have what I thought would be a simple task: create two input fields on a scene and perform the usual input methods on them (touch to set input focus, allow text entry using on-screen keyboard, deselect field when "Done" key is pressed, re-establish input focus if the field is touched/selected again, etc.), basically the usual functionality that you see in most applications that allow user text input.

I have looked through most of the relevant forums for iOS development, especially StackOverflow, and I have only seen incomplete code snippets and vague references, some of which don't even exist anymore.

I thought that this would be a simple task, but everyone seems to think that vague directions are sufficient for someone who just simply wants a straight answer.

Can someone provide a complete description of what needs to be done to accomplish this task?

Thanks.

p.s.:  After realizing that I didn't provide complete information, this is the environment and tools that I'm using:

Library Framework: Cocos2D v2
Development Studio: Xcode 5.1
Target Platforms: iOS on iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch devices (port to Android platforms in progress)
Minimum iOS required: 6.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Cocos2d v3, use `CCTextField` for text input. For example:

```
CCTextField *enterName = [CCTextField textFieldWithSpriteFrame:[CCSpriteFrame frameWithImageNamed:@"textfield_background.png"]];
enterName.fontSize = 16.0f;
enterName.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100.0f, 50.0f);
enterName.preferredSize =CGSizeMake(100.0f, 50.0f);
enterName.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
enterName.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f);
[self addChild:enterName z:5];
```

If you are using Cocos2d v2, use UIKit components. For example:

```
CGSize size = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(size.width * 0.5,
                                                                       size.height* 0.1,
                                                                       100, 100)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view]addSubview:textField];
```

As a note, Cocos2d v3 actually uses a `UITextField` in iOS and a `NSTextField` in Mac.

```
#ifdef __CC_PLATFORM_IOS
/** iOS: UITextField used by the CCTextField. */
@property (nonatomic,readonly) UITextField* textField;
#elif defined(__CC_PLATFORM_MAC)

/** Mac: NSTextField used by the CCTextField. */
@property (nonatomic,readonly) NSTextField* textField;
#endif
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using v3, I'm still using v2, but thanks.

Comment: By the way, I would like to thank you for providing a complete code example, instead of the idiotic "try this" one-liner statements that some people think are so clever but really provide no help at all...

Comment: Updated answer to account for v2.

Comment: **THANK YOU** so much for following up on this.  Your solution worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use basic UIView and add it over the cocos2d layers, using this code:

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] addSubview:yourCustomView];
```

Comment: OK, thanks for responding, but this is exactly the type of vague direction that I mentioned in my question: it's not an answer, it's an indication of the direction that you took, with no real "meat" to it.